# Intersect (Knife) not working correctly

Tags: vertices, edges, topology, knife-tool

I want my mesh to connect so I attempted Intersect (Knife). As you can see these edges are not connected, I pulled it away for the picture so you can see the topology.

[image]

So I selected these faces and used Intersect (Knife)...

[image]

Then it looks like there was added vertices. However if the vertex is grabbed and pulled away, you will see that only one of the faces, meaning that I can't merge doubles because the other face doesn't have any vertices added from this operation.

[image]

Comment: Intersect works well of clearly intersecting geometry, not coplanar tangentially grazing barely touching edges.

Comment: Then how to merge them?

Comment: Lots of ways. Off the top of my head, erase the big face and extrude the three edges to the side until the fill the remaining gap.